# How do I migrate my Nginx's rewrite rules from dotCloud to Next dotcloud?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, dotcloud, cloudcontrol

I have migrated a `static` app from dotcloud to Next dotCloud and found that my nginx regrite rules didn't work.

They redirect from

`miappname.dotcloudapp.com/oldurl`

to

`miappname.dotcloudapp.com:someport/newurl`

instead of

`miappname.dotcloudapp.com/newurl`

Answer (score 0):

The old nginx's `rewrite` rules must be migrated to by adding the domain name explicitly as follows.

Old rule

```
rewrite ^/oldurl /newurl redirect;
```

New rule

```
rewrite ^/oldurl $scheme://$host/newurl redirect;
```